# Android AlertDialog with custom view: get input data

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have an application with an AlertDialog that shows a single EditText. I followed the Android developers guide to do it, but I can't find how to get the data entered by the user.

The custom layout only has an EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/license_value"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/license" />
```

I'm using a DialogFragment to create the dialog. To get the data back when the user clicks the ok button I'm using an interface.

```
public class EditLicenseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public interface EditLicenseDialogListener {
        public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String value);
    }

    private EditLicenseDialogListener mListener;

    // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            mListener = (EditLicenseDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
             throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle(R.string.new_license);

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_license, null))

        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // GET VALUE. HOW TO DO IT?
                EditText valueView = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.license_value);
                if(valueView == null) Log.d("AA", "NULL");
                else{
                    String value = valueView.getText().toString();
                    mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(EditLicenseDialogFragment.this, value);
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                EditLicenseDialogFragment.this.getDialog().cancel();
            }
        }); 

        return builder.create();

    }
}
```

In my activity I do the following:

```
public class LicenseListActivity extends FragmentActivity 
    implements EditLicenseDialogFragment.EditLicenseDialogListener{

    ...

    findViewById(R.id.buttonAddLicense).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    DialogFragment dialog = new EditLicenseDialogFragment(true);
                    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "EditLicenseDialogFragment");
                }
            });

    @Override
    public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog, String value) {
       Log.d("TAG", value);
    }
```

The EditText I try to retrieve inside the DialogFragment is always NULL. How can I get the value of the EditText?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that's because view in which you are trying to find your edittext is not correct.

It should be something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_license, null);
builder.setView(dialogView)
.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            EditText valueView = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.license_value); //here
            if(valueView == null) Log.d("AA", "NULL");
            else{
                String value = valueView.getText().toString();
                mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(EditLicenseDialogFragment.this, value);
            }
        })
```

Comment: I tried this but on the line, where valueView is initialized, the compiler gives me an error: " Cannot refer to a non-final variable diag_view inside an inner class defined in a different method". If I make dialogView a final variable, it will not be changed and nothing can be retrieved from it.

Comment: So, declare `View dialogView` outside a method, as a class field.

Comment: You need to declare `dialogView` as `final` -> `final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_license, null);`. Only then you can use it inside anonymous class `OnClickListener`.